# Optimize postgress update query with join statement on large tables

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, inner-join

I have 2 tables A and B.
A contains ~6M records and B ~1M records.
B contains foreign key to A, column name a_id.
I need to move the relationship between the tables, so table A will contain b_id, and remove the a_id from B.

I created this migration:

```
UPDATE A
SET b_id = B.id
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON B.a_id = A.id;
```

This is the explain query:

```
"Update on A  (cost=64444.71..138800306174.79 rows=7984529761815 width=915)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=64444.71..138800306174.79 rows=7984529761815 width=915)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on A  (cost=0.00..485941.45 rows=5779245 width=899)"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=64444.71..642396.62 rows=1381587 width=16)"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=64444.71..628741.69 rows=1381587 width=16)"
"                    Hash Cond: (A.id = B.a_id)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on A  (cost=0.00..485941.45 rows=5779245 width=10)"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=40427.87..40427.87 rows=1381587 width=14)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on B (cost=0.00..40427.87 rows=1381587 width=14)"
```

This is taking too long(More than half an hour), more than my time window i have for the migration. Is there anything to do in order to optimize the update statement?

Comment: There is no `UPDATE` in your update statement. (also: it *looks* like you are repeating your target table in your `from` list)

Comment: @wildplasser Correct, Was copying issue, I editted my question. Thanks.

Comment: `UPDATE A
SET b_id = B.id
FROM B
WHERE B.a_id = A.id;` <<-- don't repeat the target table in the from-list. (this must be a duplicate ...)

Comment: @wildplasser I tried this one before I used the inner join, And it also took the same amount of time. Is there anything left to optimize the query?

Comment: Your tables should have a structure. A.id could have an index, and B.a_id should be unique.

Comment: @wildplasser Thank you a lot! I examined my "before" query again and it was different than what you suggested above. Removing the double from + adding index solve the issue :)